# What is the benefit of the Dart language over JavaScript (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, dart

I don't see the point of [Dart](http://www.dartlang.org/) in terms of the problem they are trying to solve.

I read that it was created due to short comings of JavaScript, however those short comings were not given.

Can someone explain the benefit of learning Dart rather than me learning Node.js?

Comment: for the record, there already is a language solving javascript's so called problems: Coffeescript http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/

Comment: @Comptrol: since Coffeescript has a very direct mapping to JavaScript it *can't* do *some* of the things that dart attempts to do. For example it can't really do static typing without introducing a lot more complexity to the language.

Comment: Dart's VM (like Node) has direct support for server side programming (IO etc.) although its currently not very well documented (as the API is stil stabilizing). But you would go ahead and write your new Dart Sinatra clone.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The [technical overview](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/technical-overview/index.html) seems to summarize the difference quite well:

- classes: while JavaScript *is* object oriented and it *does not* provide classes (at least in its latest incarnations), it is really a prototype-based language and not a class-based language. While that is not inherently *worse*, it is different from most major OO languages, which makes it harder to learn for most people.
- (optional) static typing: You can't do static typing (as in: "checked by the compiler") in plain JavaScript. The advantages (and disadvantages) are well-known and have been widely discussed.
- language support for libraries: "loading that file before this" is a very primitive way of implementing libraries and *most* modern languages have explicit support for libraries in some way.

That page also mentions tooling, but that's not an inherent difference between languages. Granted, a statically compiled and typed language is *easier* to write good tools for, but this is not a fundamental difference that can't be solved by programming.

Comment: " which makes it harder to learn for most people." The prototypical OO learning curve is a day of effort. I doubt this has any kind of real negative impact. "language support for libraries:" Plenty of JS tools to do it, ES6 will also have this. The only useful feature is static typing.

Comment: I can somehow elieve the "one day effort" *if* the learner has not learned class-based OO before. If one *has* learned that before, then the "unlearning" involved will make it a lot harder. And "lots of JS tools to do libraries" *is* part of the problem: there's no single unified way. What if 3 of your libraries use 3 different mechanisms?

Comment: I think Javascript should not be presented as OO language. It is Object based, or prototype-based but not Object Oriented as it doesn't provide classes, inheritance, polymorphism, etc.

Comment: @Snicolas: being class-based is not a prerequisite to being object-oriented. All those features you mention are *not required* for an object oriented language, they are simply very common. "Object oriented" is now often used as a synonym for "class based", but that's simply not true.

Comment: Interesting, why don't we try TypeScript? It compiles to JS and solve our issues listed.

Answer (score 64):

The main issue I see it as solving that of creating large, multi-developer applications.

In Javascript, I can write the perfectly valid code:

```
function x(y) {
 return y*y;      
}

document.write(x(3,4,5));
```

And this will execute fine, but it's blatantly an error.

Now separate the function definition and the function call by several developers and several months over a codebase of several thousand lines of code.

The original function x(y)  could have originally been function x(y,z,a) but has since been refactored over time.   This is where javascript fails for me, and this is what dart will help resolve.

**Edit (May 2013)** In addition to my answer above, which I believe still holds true, I think that the performance story is also getting pretty compelling.  Lars Bak and Kasper Lund's [talk from Google I/O](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsGgfUreyZw) provides some evidence.

Comment: You can trivially use documentation to solve this problem. All your saying is it's harder to write bad code using a more restrictive tool. That's a band aid, the correct solution is to not write bad code.

Comment: Documentation cannot refactor your code!

Comment: @Raynos It's easier to write good code when it's harder to write bad code.

Comment: @Max And it's also harder to write good code because Dart is restrictive and get's in the way.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about JavaScript is that it's a cheap language. And that's a one major thing...

Comment: A good answer but wouldn't a healthy TDD approach reduce/eliminate cases like these.

Comment: Yes, TDD also helps, but it's a manual process (that needs manual code reviews and such to enforce it).  Tooling isn't a silver bullet, but it's something that will help provide an extra layer.

Comment: @Raynos Yeah! Because everyone always keeps documentation up to date, and there are never mistakes in documentation!